# How can I prove this $P(A)=P(A \cap B)+P(A \cap B^c)$?

Tags: probability

How can I prove this $P(A)=P(A \cap B)+P(A \cap B^c)$ formula?

Is this formula only applicable for disjoint events?

Comment: Hint: What this is saying is that the event $A$ can be divided into the cases where $B$ occurs and where $B$ doesn't occur.  Therefore, one would expect this statement to be true.  In particular, use inclusion / exclusion on the RHS and observe that $A\cap B$ and $A\cap B^c$ are disjoint events.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with Wei's answer, but I started typing this and it is a different approach, so I'm going to post. Note that if you drew a Venn diagram, it would be obvious; just as Wei said, if you have to stick an element **e** into the set A, it will either be in B or not in B, which is basically all that says.

Anyway, another approach:

As pointed out, I have to split the answer into two cases:
if $P(A) = 0$, then ...
$$P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^c) = P(0 \cap B) + P(0 \cap B^c) = 0$$

Otherwise:

$$ P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^c) $$
$$ = P(A)P(B \mid A) + P(A)P(B^c \mid A) $$
$$ = P(A)\big( P(B \mid A) + P(B^c \mid A)\big)$$
$$ = P(A)\big( P(B \mid A) + \big(1 - P(B \mid A)\big)\big)$$
$$ = P(A)(1) $$
$$ = P(A) $$

The brackets get confusing, sorry. The main trick here is that the probability of a complement is equal to 1 minus that probability. As Wei says, this is regardless of whether the events are disjoint or not.

Comment: What are values of $P(B|A)$ and $P(B^c|A)$ if $P(A)=0$?

Comment: True, I shouldn't neglect that case. A bit lazy of me. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This merely reports the task on showing that $P(B\mid A)+P(B^c\mid A)=1$, a (true) inequality which is not easier to prove than the desired one.

Comment: Perhaps. I often see the inclusion-exclusion principle taken as (almost) an axiom. We can get $P(B \mid A) + P(B^c \mid A) = 1$ from there (given the limitations as pointed out by drhab). If I wanted to take it all the way back to the third axiom, I think this can be done, but I didn't feel it was necessary. I don't know of such a simple journey from the original question, though I agree it is no less intuitive - but there are plenty of answers here that appeal to that intuition, such as Wei's which I pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

It applies to any events.

If A and B are joint events, i.e. their intersection is not empty.  Then for any elements **e** in A, **e** is either in the intersection or not, thus $P(A)=P(A\wedge B)+P(A\wedge B^c).$

If A and B are disjoint, $P(A\wedge B)=0$.  Then $P(A)=P(A\wedge B^c)$.

Answer (score 0):

A defining property of a [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure#Definition) $P:\mathcal A\to[0,1]$ is:

> If $A_1,A_2,\dots$ are disjoint then $P(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n)$.

Application on $A_n=\varnothing$ for each $n$ leads to $P(\varnothing)=0$.

Then a second application on $A_1=A\cap B$, $A_2=A\cap B^c$ and $A_3=A_4=\cdots=\varnothing$ leads to the formula mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple to answer.Here A intersection B and A intersection B^c are mutually exclusive.Now use the law of addition for mutually exclusive event and then simplify the event.You will get A.Hence,P(A) is our required answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms) third axiom states:

$P\left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty E_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(E_i).$

---

Set $w.o.g$:

$E_1 = A \cap B$, $E_2 = A \cap B^c$ and $ E_i=\varnothing \ \ for \ \ i\geq 3$.

---

Note that by using set theory one can show that:

$ (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c) = (B \cup B^c) \cap A = A$ see [example 1.11.2](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~pkirby/mad2104/SlideShow/s4_1.pdf)

---

Plugging the $E_i$'s into the third axiom and using the claim above:

$P(E_1\bigcup E_2) = P((A \cap B) \bigcup (A \cap B^c)) = P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^c)$